# dimensions not returned by AppNexus API

Tags: rest

I'm trying to setup an integration with the [AppNexus reporting API](https://wiki.appnexus.com/display/sdk/Publisher+Analytics+Report#PublisherAnalyticsReport-Example), ran into problems, and wonder if anyone in the StackOverflow community has some insight to share.

The AppNexus API has a walk-though using `curl` and it sort-of works, except that the groups/dimensions don't get returned. Here's what I did:

There's a file called `auth` containing our credentials:

```
# JSON file containing our credentials
$ cat auth
{
    "auth": {
        "username" : "ourAppNexusApiUsername",
        "password" : "ourSecretApiUserPassword"
    }
}
```

There's also a JSON file containing a query. Note the dimensions in the "columns" list:

```
# The query itself, in JSON format. 
$ cat query.json 
{
    "report": {
        "format": "csv",
        "report_interval": "yesterday",
        "groups": [
            "publisher_id",
            "imp_type",
            "geo_country",
            "placement_id"
        ],
        "columns": [
            "imps_total",
            "imps_kept",
            "imps_resold",
            "publisher_filled_revenue",
            "total_convs"
        ],
        "report_type": "publisher_analytics"
    }
}
```

I'm able to authenticate:

```
$ curl -b cookies -c cookies -X POST -d @auth 'https://api.appnexus.com/auth'

{"response":{"status":"OK","token":"hbapi:133820:5571c87753c27:nym2","dbg_info":{"instance":"56.bm-hbapi.prod.lax1","slave_hit":false,"db":"master","parent_dbg_info":{"instance":"63.bm-hbapi.prod.nym2","slave_hit":false,"db":"master","parent_dbg_info":{"instance":"38.bm-api.prod.nym2","slave_hit":false,"db":"master","time":482.32913017273,"version":"1.15.279","warnings":[],"slave_lag":0,"start_microtime":1433520246.311},"awesomesauce_cache_used":false,"count_cache_used":false,"warnings":[],"time":1078.0298709869,"start_microtime":1433520246.2796,"version":"1.15.527","slave_lag":0,"output_term":"not_found"},"awesomesauce_cache_used":false,"count_cache_used":false,"warnings":[],"time":1360.9290122986,"start_microtime":1433520246.1491,"version":"1.15.527","slave_lag":1,"output_term":"not_found","master_instance":"63.bm-hbapi.prod.nym2","proxy":true,"master_time":1078.0298709869}}}
```

I can request a report for a given publisher. It returns a `report_id`: 72734c3a2df81522c7bae6684cfdd65c

```
$ curl -b cookies -c cookies -X POST -d @query.json 'http://api.appnexus.com/report?publisher_id=510332'

{"response":{"status":"OK","report_id":"72734c3a2df81522c7bae6684cfdd65c","existing":false,"cached":true,"dbg_info":{"instance":"58.bm-hbapi.prod.lax1","slave_hit":false,"db":"master","reads":0,"read_limit":100,"read_limit_seconds":60,"writes":1,"write_limit":60,"write_limit_seconds":60,"parent_dbg_info":{"instance":"61.bm-hbapi.prod.nym2","slave_hit":false,"db":"master","reads":0,"read_limit":100,"read_limit_seconds":60,"writes":1,"write_limit":60,"write_limit_seconds":60,"awesomesauce_cache_used":false,"count_cache_used":false,"warnings":[],"time":264.3940448761,"start_microtime":1433520268.8354,"version":"1.15.527","output_term":"not_found","reporting_dbg_info":{"instance":"11.bm-report-processor.prod.nym2","version":"1.72.130","time":1094.5529937744,"start_microtime":1433520268,"warnings":[],"api_cache_hit":"0","output_term":null}},"awesomesauce_cache_used":false,"count_cache_used":false,"warnings":[],"time":1238.8980388641,"start_microtime":1433520267.9206,"version":"1.15.527","output_term":"not_found","master_instance":"61.bm-hbapi.prod.nym2","proxy":true,"master_time":264.3940448761}}}
```

I'm able to download the report but, sadly, *the report groups are missing*:

```
$ curl -b cookies -c cookies 'http://api.appnexus.com/report-download?id=72734c3a2df81522c7bae6684cfdd65c'

imps_total,imps_kept,imps_resold,publisher_filled_revenue,total_convs
65086432,0,42898432,1234.776809,4
```

I imagine that I'm not the first person to encounter this. Anyone have any thoughts/suggestions?

*Edit:*

I uploaded a [quick & dirty Python script to a Github repo](https://github.com/alexwoolford/appnexusApiTest) to make it easier to test.

Also, AppNexus responded, via email:

> It looks like you got your hands on some documentation for mobile
>   reporting, rather than for our standard publisher analytics report.
>   You should change "groups" to "row_per" like this:"

```
{
    "report": {
        "format": "csv",
        "report_interval": "yesterday",
        "row_per": [
            "hour"
        ],
        "columns": [
            "imps_total"
        ],
        "report_type": "publisher_analytics"
    }
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have also CLI access? Perhaps with `manage-netezza-table list` you could see whether you actually have such columns

Comment: Thanks @avnr. I've not used the appnexus-cli before. Trying it now.

Comment: I spun-up a CentOS VM and tried to install the CLI per the documentation (https://wiki.appnexus.com/display/documentation/Yum+Repository+Configuration+Files). It wasn't able to resolve the repo: `Couldn't resolve host 'yum.local.appnexus.net'`

Comment: Well it would help to verify my assumption, by CLI or otherwise, but even without such verification it looks like the problem isn't the retrieval of the groups, but that the report you requested doesn't have such a selector in the first place. As you can see in AppNexus' support email, they don't list `groups` as a selector in their example. You should try instead using `row_per` with a single group qualifier, e.g., `row_per: [ "publisher_id" ]` and produce a report for each group separately. Hopefully you'll hit one or more groups that are supported, then you can combine them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AppNexus console](https://console.appnexus.com) (Appnexus' web-UI) uses the same API to provide content.

If you're able to produce the output you're looking for by running a report, you can reverse engineer the API calls by clicking on the 'OPEN API VIEWER' at the bottom of the screen. That'll show you the API parameters used to create the report.

Answer (score 1):

AppNexus tech writer here (months later!). I'm pretty sure the
example reporting API call on that page was wrong (and I've just
fixed it – you can check it out [here](https://wiki.appnexus.com/display/sdk/Publisher+Analytics+Report#PublisherAnalyticsReport-Example)).

My understanding after testing the reporting API calls out is that:

1. The "bad" example from the docs doesn't work (as you said – now
   fixed)
2. You do get grouping behavior as long as you are grouping data
   (using "row_per") that you explicitly asked for (using
   "columns").

In other words, you must ask for data fields in "columns" and then
group them (or more likely a subset) using "row_per".  Here's the
example I used in the updated docs:

```
{
    "report": {
        "report_type": "publisher_analytics",
        "report_interval": "yesterday",
        "columns": [
            "geo_country",
            "imp_type",
            "placement",
            "clicks",
            "total_convs",
            "publisher_revenue"
        ],
        "groups": [
            "geo_country",
            "imp_type",
            "placement",
        "imps_total"
        ],
        "name": "Publisher Analytics - 10/30/2015"
    }
}
```

I used quotes around "bad" above because I'm not sure if it's a bug
in our API or the expected behavior - I'm trying to find that out
with our engineering team now, but it's Friday afternoon, so I may
have to check in again later.

In any case, I've updated the example on [the page](https://wiki.appnexus.com/x/qAN-Aw) to reflect the
actual behavior as tested for the time being.

Two more things:

1. That page **is** for our regular publisher analytics report.  It's
   not mobile-specific, we just published it there too so it'd be
   available externally for some of our customers' customers.
   Sorry for the confusion!
2. According to my testing this afternoon, "row_per" and
   "groups" both work, and exhibit the same behavior.

I'm probably too late to help you out, but hopefully this is useful to someone!